# asp.core windows authentication integration tests fails with No authentication handler is configured

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.Core web app that uses windows authentication I am trying to setup integration tests for.

inside the startup the authorization is configured as follows

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("SiteRead", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(
                context => context.User.HasClaim(
                    x => x.Value == "groupSidHere" 
                )));
        });
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
```

The test is as follows

```
        var server = new TestServer(builder);
        var client = server.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

The test fails with the following response

InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

All the documentation I have been able to find for integration tests doesn't cover this scenario(windows auth). Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/924), they say:

> We ended up solving our need for Windows auth with TestServer by creating a little library that will inject some windows auth services into the pipeline to emulate the behavior provided by IIS - you can find it at

You will find their library "IntelliTect.AspNetCore.TestHost.WindowsAuth" [here](https://github.com/IntelliTect/AspNetCore.TestHost.WindowsAuth).

I faced the same issue, and that library worked for me!

And it actually inject real windows authentication data, not just a mock data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20139938)

Comment: Thank u very much for the advice